# Android - How to create Multiple instances of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, multiple-instances

I was wondering is it possible to create multiple instances of a single Activity in Android?

I currently start my own inCall screen for a Voip Test by using the following code:

---

```
     public void initInCallScreen(String pName, String phoneNumber, int contactID, boolean 
        callDirection, int lineID){

    //starts in callScreen dialog
    final Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, CallDialogActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("NAME", pName);
    myIntent.putExtra("NUMBER", phoneNumber);
    myIntent.putExtra("ID", contactID);
    myIntent.putExtra("CALLTYPE", callDirection); //True = Incoming, False = Outgoing
    myIntent.putExtra("LINEID", lineID);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

---

This allows me to start the Activity fine.

However when I call it for a second it just returns to the Activity already created rather than creating a new Activity and placing it on the stack.

I would like to be able to create the activity multiple times so that I have two or 3 Activities on the stack and the user can switch between them, using Home, Back buttons etc...

Is this possible and if so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i haven't done the proper research but given your description, i'm guessing that `CallDialogActivity` is of the `single top` launch mode, in which case i don't think there's much you can do. if this was not specified explicitly, it would default to the behavior that you're requesting...

Comment: Is there a way to check if it is single top?

Comment: @DonalRafferty were you able to solve this problem..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> However when I call it for a second it
>   just returns to the Activity already
>   created rather than creating a new
>   Activity and placing it on the stack.

You probably changed your manifest to add an `android:launchMode` attribute that is interfering with your goal. By default, starting an activity starts a new instance.

Also:

- Get rid of `myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`, since you do not want a new task based on what you have written here
- Since `context` is probably a `Context`, I do not know why you are going through all of the `ContextWrapper` / `getBaseContext()` stuff

Comment: Sorry, moving old code into a new project, thanks for pointing the context out. When I remove myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); I get the following error when trying to start the Activity :AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

So I'm not sure but I think I need the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag set? Also, there is no launchMode setting anywhere in my manifest.

Comment: @Donal Rafferty: Where are you launching this from?

Comment: From a Service within the same Application.

Comment: @Donal Rafferty: Hmmm...I have never started an activity from a service, so I don't know how the rules differ. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```