# Android History creating new Activity and not from Stack

Tags: android

For example, consider a task consisting of four activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the history stack, with this resulting order:  A, C, D, B. But my requirement is the resulting order should be  A, B, C, D, B. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157596/android-how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-an-activity/3157703#3157703) will definitely help you. (Also possible dupe ?)

- You probably have to remove the `android:launchMode` attribute

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but by setting activity param android:launchMode="singleTask" you'll achieve what you need.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" ... android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

With this variant only one instance of activity will ever be created, so be careful.